# Delphi time graph splitting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, delphi, split

I have 3 records in ClientDataSet with structure:

> Num: integer; Start: TTime; End: TTime;

```
1; 9:00; 10:00
2; 9:30; 10:00
3; 9:40; 10:20
```

I have to get those records to other ClientDataSet like this:

```
1; 9:00; 9:30
2: 9:30; 9:40
3; 9:40; 10:00
4; 10:00; 10:20
```

Comment: When describing an algorithm requirement you *must* do more than provide a sample of input and output data.  We have to guess at what the algorithm is here - there could be many algorithms that provide the correct answer for your given data but only one that does what you want.  Explain in words what you need to accomplish.  My first guess is that you are trying to generate a minimized list of non-overlapping time intervals into which you can bin overlapping events.  Is this correct?

Comment: looks like school classes homework ?

Comment: You can use SQL instead of Delphi. See UNION and OVER documentation for details.

Comment: @Abelisto sure, but he already got it into CDS, perhaps his program never used any SQL, even embedded ones. Though actually, instead of UNION i'd prefer to sorted queries and merging-sort them on client or in stored-proc

Comment: It is not homework. CDS data is from csv file.

Comment: it seems that using CDS just to read or create CSV is a bit overkill, but up to you. If that short samples are the typical workload, then no reason to think about algorithms, difference would be non-significant. Just use stock algorithms of Delphi RTL and that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `TList<TTime>`, populate it with both columns, sort it, then iterate through the list skipping duplicates. Like this.

```
var l: TList<TTime>; t1, t2: TTime; id2: cardinal;
begin
  l := TList<TTime>.Create;
  try
    cds1.First;
    while not cds1.Eof do begin
       l.Add( Frac(cds1.Fields[1].AsDateTime) );
       l.Add( Frac(cds1.Fields[2].AsDateTime) );
       cds1.Next;   
    end;

    l.Sort;

    cds2.Clear;
    if l.Count <= 0 then exit;

    t1 := l[0]; id2 := 0;
    for t2 in l do begin
        if t1 > t2 then raise Exception.create ('Sort silently failed!') else
        if t1 < t2 then begin
           Inc(id2);
           cds2.AppendRecord([ id2, t1, t2 ]);
           t1 := t2;
        end;
    end;
  finally 
    l.Free;
  end;
end;
```